# sql insert statement to set rows proportional

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a table with the following data (ofcourse there are many rows).

```
metric_id(int) | employee_id (string) | quota (double)
1              | abcd                 | 100
1              | wxyz                 | 120
```

What i want to do is a `SQL` `INSERT` that takes all values with a specific `metric_id`.

```
select * from mytable where metric_id=1;
```

Then use the results to create new entries with different metric_id that will have the quota value set at a specific proportion. (ie: metric_id=2 quota is 50% of metric_id=1)

So my end table after the insert would look like

```
metric_id(int) | employee_id (string) | quota (double)
1              | abcd                 | 100
1              | wxyz                 | 120
2              | abcd                 | 50
2              | wxyz                 | 60
```

Can this be done in one sql statement? I would like to use prepared statement to prevent inject if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It should be what you need.

```
insert into some_table 
(metric_id, employee_id, quota)
select 
2, employee_id, quota * 0.5
from 
some_table 
where
metric_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

More alternative way (no where clause needed):

```
INSERT INTO TableName
(metric_id,employee_id,quota)
SELECT metric_id+1,employee_id,quota/2
FROM TableName
```